# Payments without private key/address in wallet [OWN COIN]

Tags: transactions, altcoin, payment, cryptography

currently I am creating/sharing an own crypto currency. Details about it are that it is a Scrypt Coin with Proof-Of-Work. But that's not really the question.

I will build a website around the coin and want to make users be able to create transactions without that their private key / wallet gets into my wallet (the websites wallet). For example I could create new wallets each time a user registers and show the private key with dumpprivatekey and RPC. But I want to make them to be able to make transactions with just entering their privatekey but without my website saving it or even their address later would be in the projects wallet. Best example for this is myetherwallet.com. Users enter their private key but the only location where this is saved is in an cookie on the users computer, not the website or any server of them itself.
I hope you understand what I mean.

Thank you!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: and you shouldn't proceed this way. It is a security issue by design, giving private keys over a web interface or storing priv keys in cookies or similiar. Read first about how to secure private keys, get along with the principles of HD wallets and its keys, and then try to implement a solution. Otherwise you will loose the funds for the keys!

Comment: I know what a HD wallet is. But the wallet would be controlled with RPC requests from the website / website server to the wallet system. If this way would be hacked, I would not only lose my, no, I would lose all wallets private keys and everyone who is registered on my website could lose his funds. This is why I want a way on making transactions without having their privatekeys stored on my servers, except on their systems.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script that gernerates a private key, then a public key, then the adress. You connect the adress with the user and ask him to copy the private key and safe it secure. When he/she wants to make a transaction, you ask for the private key, get it to your backend that makes the transaction...

By the way:

> is saved in a cookie on the users computer

That sounds terrible because you had access to the key if you had access to the computer and users sometimes delete their cookies...

Comment: The thing is, I do not want to store any address of any user in my web wallet / project wallet. The user should only have to enter his privatekey, without this saved on my service or in any of my databases - same as MyEtherWallet does (as I wrote before..). I have no problem with entering my Privatekey again and again on MyEtherWallet and I think the users of my project wouldn't have too.

Answer (score 0):

Lol...
1. Why do you dislike? I can for sure ask a question without using this "?".
And I did. My question was simple, how to create a transaction without saving the users address/wallet in my wallet because that wouldn't be removeable.

2. So you tell me, that saving the users wallet, including their private key, in my wallet, would be safer than just saving the private key in a cookie? While the one way would permanently save the privatekey in a wallet and could be hacked at any time, the last way is only hackable for a short period of time.

I don't know why you can't just answer the question instead of criticize my question.